# File upload download ability for MVC 3 razor view view attached image

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, razor

I need your help with file upload and download capabilities for an MVC 3 razor view application.

[image]

Above is how I want to be able to add files to a form that I am submitting to database. I can manage the back end part, SQL/Stored procedure etc... but the view is the main issue.

I am not a scripting guy so I need your guidance in being able to do this.

I want to be able to click on a link just like above "attach another file" and get a dialogue file selection pop up ( I have done this part but if you have better ideas please let me know) .

Each file I select I want to view just like above picture with a check box on the left.. and should be able to select as many as I want.

Once that is done, on submit or upload I want to be able to upload them or if unchecked not load them..

Thanks folks !

Comment: [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)? Right now you sound like a customer in a shop explaining your requirements to the vendor. Unfortunately StackOveflow is not a shop, you are not a customer and we are not vendors.

Comment: excuse me if I offended you, I went to your posts and here is the question you actually answered "I want to upload an excel file in asp.net mvc3.0. How can I upload the file using html input file control." to without offending the person who posted the question. Thanks for down voting, I was just trying to explain in detail what I need to do and I only wanted to know if anyone can guide me to the right direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the jquery plugin.

http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/multiple-file-upload/

It does not use flash. I have no problem with any browser. Works on all browsers.

Comment: Thanks Ibrahim ... as I previously stated I did look into that and since this is an ideal suggestion I will mark it as answered.

Answer (score 1):

If you type in google "Ajax multi file upload in asp.net mvc" the first result will give you answer

http://valums.com/ajax-upload/

It is too complex to be written in 5 minutes, there is a million libraries, you have to pick one, and I'm sure there is one available trough nuget

http://nuget.org/packages/FreshUpload

Neat :)

Comment: just update my answer, I managed to find one in nuget repository :) http://nuget.org/packages/FreshUpload

Comment: I had looked at the ajax-upload before .. FreshUpload never heard of it.. I will look into this as well.. there is another jquery file upload .. but it is NOT working properly with IE .. or http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/multiple-file-upload/

Comment: FreshUpload has Silverlight fallback, and if you don't want it then you have to use flash version like http://www.uploadify.com/

Comment: I can not use flash or silverlight .. I just got downloaded the FreshUpload and noticed that :)

Comment: if you dont have fallback suport IE<9 will fail since mentioned are built on HTML5 standard.... I dont have any preference to MS web helpers since never used it, as a matter of fact, I totally left MS platform and now coding in ruby on rails :)

Comment: I have done some Ruby on rails... read couple of book on it too.. it is interesting.. but not sure if it is getting any popularity .. I know there are only few ROR developers... and it is very high on demand.